# Подход для загрузки сложного графа объектов из БД

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Доброго времени суток.

**Задача:** в некотором WEB приложении имеется БД со следующей структурой таблиц
[image]

и набор классов со следующей структурой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо загрузить объект Dish из БД по его ID включая все объекты, которые он должен содержать, с учетом того, что БД и модель находятся на разных серверах.

**Вопрос:**
Стоит ли пытаться загрузить все одним запросом или стоит как-то разбить загрузку на несколько подзапросов? Если стоит разбить на несколько подзапросов, то по какому принципу проводить разбиение?

Comment: Я бы в первую очередь для себя ответил: "А нужен ли в моём сценарии этот объект полностью?". Какой бизнес сценарий вы хотите воспроизвести подняв весь объект Dish с зависимыми обьъектами? Это чревато растратой памяти.

Comment: Он точно нужен полностью. Пользователю нужно отобразить блюдо и его подробный состав на одной странице.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда варианта в целом 3: 1. Составить один большой запрос с использованием JDBC и в ручную построить объект. 2. Построить его с использованием JPA. 3. Возможно сделать связывание DishIngridient и Product по UUID, а не по объектам и организовать разные репозитории. У Вас явно выражено несколько агрегатов, а вы связываете их по ссылкам, что создаёт сильную связанность. Так же отображение на одной странице является конечным уровнем функции представления, а вот из скольких хранилищь вы достанете это более важно. Так что я за третий вариант.